# Google Plus Authorship not working

Tags: search-engine, google-plus

I know there are already 1 topic on this, but mine is a lil different.

I have added all the markup required for Google Plus verification, its been 1months now still it doesn't showup on google search with my picture.

my website: http://www.ajinkyaxjs.com

I have added below in my HTML page:

```
<link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/+AjinkyaBorade?rel=author"/>
    <link rel="publisher" href="https://plus.google.com/+AjinkyaBorade?rel=publisher"/>
<a href="https://plus.google.com/+AjinkyaBorade?rel=author" style="display:none"></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two way connection is not validating for Google. Use Google's [structured data testing tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http://www.ajinkyaxjs.com/) to validate the markup and connections are correct.

Comment: I have already seen that tool, but dont know whats wrong. Added every meta. and link backs

Comment: I removed HTTPS from google plus links now, since my website doesnt have SSL.

Comment: I think the problem is you have a link back to your site but it's not under the "Contributor to' section on your G+ about page.

Comment: DONE, it fixed it. I just added my website under contributed to.